# Any reason to create weak references upon instantiation in python

Tags: python, weak-references

I was looking through some code in Python 3.2 and I came across something that looked... interesting. It was a class that allowed users to make weak references to the object upon instantiating the object. This was the code:

```
class ReferableObject:

    __instanceheap__ = []

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__instanceheap__.append(self)
        return self
```

I guess the point is that trying to create a weak reference to an object upon instantiation causes the weakref to die immediately:

```
>>> class A:
        pass

>>> a = weakref.ref(A())
>>> a() is None
True
>>> class B(ReferableObject):
        pass
>>> b = weakref.ref(B())
>>> b() is None
False
```

While slightly amusing, this seems kind of useless to me. And the way the instances are stored such that they don't die upon immediately referencing them seems amateurish at best. What reasons might someone have to want to make a weak reference upon instantiation?

Comment: Seeing as this just *leaks* all instances, making them live forever, it's pretty pointless to have a weakref at all, let alone as the sole visible/in-use reference. Or is there some code that removes objects from `__instanceheap__`?

Comment: There was nothing as far as I could tell. It just left them there.

Comment: Does anything anywhere (possibly outside the class) access `__instanceheap__` for any reason besides adding new instances to the list?

Comment: ``make weak references to the object upon instantiating the object`` -- I see no weakref in the class ReferableObject?